How to prevent infinite background process in shopify once changed cart status
I built a js script to add cart on theme, but once I added cart, app is broken to work.
This code in template section of liquid.
await fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(formData)
  })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    return false;
  });

Adding cart feature is working well, but once it has been done, Shopify site is broken and when I checked on windows task manager, memory consumpsion is increasing more and more with time.
If anyone experienced in such issue, please leave comments.
Thank you very much.

Hi, Are you getting any error on console or network?

@YashMaheshwari
Thank you for your reply. I can't see any error on console.
But I have got some issue on network. I will provide you screenshot of issue.
https://pasteboard.co/OWsQVlv8Fw40.png

If you are using any extensions like adblocker or something, disable them, as I can see that multiple reqeust are blocked.

It was same when I check on Guest browser(without any extension).

@YashMaheshwari
https://pasteboard.co/tK6tpXR5cTgj.png
This is issues tracked on console.

any URL on which the issue is replicated?

Yes, it's on developing progress. Can we open dm on telegram?
